# External Linux kernel module that provides kexec for ARM

Tags: linux

Sometimes kexec is not provided by running kernel, but I can compile kernel modules for it.

I want a module that can be used instead of missing kexec. It should work the same as built-in kexec, but as module.

Primary target arch is ARM, as it has more problems with unsafe kernel update compared to x86.